# Button in MFC CtreeCtrl column

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CTreeListCtrl in my MFC application.What I need to do is add a button in a particular column of a node when a particular condition is satisfied(type is changed to reference).[image: Desired effect]

In the image I have edited and added a blue rounded oval to mark the place of desired button.What I want to do is to invoke a dialog on clicking it.But I don't have any clue whether it is possible or not.If yes then pls give me some suggesions.

Answer (score 0):

This is no normal tree control. It is already customized to use multiple columns and I am sure it uses some kid of owner draw. For me it seams more like a list control with tree Features... I know some similar code from Codepproject..

Creating a "real" button (window) isn't wise/good. because it is another window inside the list control...

1. Change your code to "Draw a button. You can use DrawFrameControl.
2. Just intercept the left mouse click. Check the range if this area is cliecked. Fire a user defined message to the parent window.

Comment: Yeah you are right .. I somehow missed it. It is a CTreeListCtrl. edited in question.

Comment: @xMRi I disagree.  I don't understand your concern for dynamically adding a child control to a parent control.  Adding such a control would afford the ability to handle the click event much easier as the code would be encapsulated in a separate class.

Comment: @rriower: But not in a scrollable CListCtrl, where you might have to show thousands of lines with it...